# ExtJS MVC Controller ref to Tab Panel's active tab

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc, extjs4.1

I have an MVC app which has a [Tab Panel](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel) rendered as the only item in the viewport. Within the tabs I would like to put the same type of component, for which the event handling is equal within all tabs.

Therefore I need an ExtJS MVC [Controller ref](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-cfg-refs) to the active tab, that would lead me to execute events on the components in the active tab. Is it possible to have such a `ref`?

My current approach is this:

1. get reference to Tab Panel
2. call [getActiveTab()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel-method-getActiveTab)
3. call the controller events for the component in active tab

Is it possible to encapsulate the above 3 steps in one controller `ref`? Would be *beautiful* :-)

I'm using ExtJS 4.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I think controller refs are overrated. This sounds like a simple case where you can use one as you describe, but I prefer to listen to the event, and navigate from the firing component to the one I need.

In your case, assuming your tab panel contains regular ext panels, I'd do something like the following:

```
onButtonClick: function (button) {
    var panel = button.up('panel[tab]');

    if (panel) {
        panel.someMethod();
    }
}
```

The `up` method will find the closest ancestor that is of xtype panel and has a property named tab. If you have more specific xtypes or known properties, use those instead.

The panel should be the active one (else how was its button clicked?) but you can check that by going `up` another level to the tab panel and getting the activeTab there.

```
onButtonClick: function (button) {
    var panel = button.up('panel[tab]'),
        tabPanel = button.up('tabpanel'),
        activeTab = tabPanel && tabPanel.getActiveTab();

    if (panel && panel === activeTab) {
        panel.someMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Makes sense, +1ed your answer. I won't be working on this immediately, will mark it as correct when I come back to it, if this is indeed the way to go. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I found EXT MVC confusing at first because controllers are singletons and don't have references to the view you want. Instead, events fired by views pass the view as the first argument, so use that to find the right instance of the view you want to act on (using up and down). It didn't take too long to get the hang of. Please follow up if you run into trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Say your tabPanel has `itemId: 'content'`. Inside that panel you will have bunch of tabs and on each tab you will have bunch of buttons (as an example). And you want to handle all these button's click in one controller. Do I understand you correctly?

I believe that simple ref inside your controller would work:

```
this.control('#content button', { 
       click: this.buttonClicked
   }
});
```

Comment: Found a problem though. It happens when, to continue with your example, the `button` is found on more than one tab.

Comment: What do you mean? You do wanna limit and control not all buttons but just some of them?

Comment: I need to execute the event *only* for the button of the *active Panel*, not for each button on all of the panels.

Comment: yes but, if the tabPanel is not active, how the button will be pressed?

Comment: One button will be pressed, but the selector picks several components, and I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'internalId' of undefined`. Need to investigate further.

Comment: then again - you can always check what button, from what panel was pressed and whether this panel was active at the time - inside this buttonClicked handler